# VideoPlayer is not playing inside ListView or ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, listview, swiftui, video-player

I added a video player inside `ListView` or `ScrollView` with `ForEach`,
but it is not playing.

Note: **It will only work if it is inside `ScrollView` but without `ForEach`.**

```swift
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct Content2: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(0..<1) { index in
                videoView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct videoView: View {
    @State var player = AVPlayer()
    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
            .frame(height: 300)
            .onAppear{
                player.play()
            }
            .onDisappear {
                player.pause()
            }
            .onAppear {
                if let url2 = URL(string: "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4"){
                    player = AVPlayer(url: url2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Working code:

```swift
struct VideoCampaignView3: View {
    
    @State var player = AVPlayer()
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            //ForEach(0..<1) { index in
            VideoPlayer(player: player)                               
                .frame(height: 300)
                .onAppear{
                    player.play()
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    player.pause()
                }
                .onAppear {
                    if  let url2 = URL(string: "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4") {
                        player = AVPlayer(url: url2)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Question:

It should work with `ForEach` inside `List`.
It only works while no subview and `ScrollView`.

Comment: Your code works well for me with the ScrollView and the ForEach, and also with List.
 On MacOS 14.2, Xcode 15.1, tested on real ios17 devices (not Previews) and MacCatalyst. It could be different on older systems. Note it is easier to test with the `....1mb.mp4`. You could try with just one `.onAppear{...}` having `player.play()`, just after `player = AVPlayer(url: url2)`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine , I try with Xcode 15.0.1 and tried with iOS 17.0 simulator, it is not working for this configuration.

Comment: Xcode 15.0.1 with iOS 17.0 simulator works here with both options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it 'works' inside a ScrollView, it is probably a race condition (it shouldn't even work, or at least not consistently). You have a player as a state variable inside your view. You call play on it in the first onAppear view modifier, and then you **replace** the player with a whole new player. Just get rid of the first onAppear and add player.play() after you create the AVPlayer.

```
.onAppear {
    if let url2 = URL(string: "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4") {
        player = AVPlayer(url: url2)
        player.play()
    }
}
```